# JDBC Connector for MySQL not working in JMeter

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jmeter

As per the problems this person was having;
[JDBC Connector not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202999/jdbc-connection-configuration-for-mysql-not-working-in-jmeter)

I'm running Debian 9.1
I installed Java via the package manager
I added Java to the path in /etc/config & added JAVA_HOME to the path in /etc/environment
I then installed jmeter via the package manager
I then downloaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar and copied this to /usr/share/jmeter/lib

But after all this, I still dont get the JDBC connection option under Add->Config Element within JMeter, nor do i get any options for JDBC within JMeter.

Can anyone help me as to what im doing wrong?

While I am new to JMeter, I have successfully run simple "Hello World" HTTP requests queried from a PHP Script & a NodeJS script so far.

**Update**
Added JMeter log by request
[Jmeter log](https://zerobin.net/?c602c6c22b4db9ff#PP6TGGxhN9WtzeB3P3Ke0YlIvLZl1gaJBF6ITtuE6Pc=)

Comment: can you show what jmeter.log contains?

Comment: Yep, I updated the original question to include a link to the log

Comment: Can you show what you get when you select Add > Config Element ? Did you install 3rd party plugins ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the problem was with Jmeter on my Debian machine... (as prior to this I was trying to use it on Ubuntu Server, and it had the same issue as Debian);

But anyway, I just installed the Oracle JDK & JMeter for Windows, on my old Windows 7 laptop, dropped in the JDBC connector to the lib directory - & immediately it had the option for 'JDBC Connection', which never appeared on either the Ubuntu or Debian installs.

So if anyone else runs into this issue on Ubuntu or Debian ~ I might suggest trying a Windows 7 VM for running it.

**Note here**
This was the JMeter I installed on Windows (I didn't get it from Apache):
[JMeter for Windows](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmeterforwindows/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I cannot find JMeter JDBC components either in [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=jmeter) or in [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) repositories, maybe it wasn't included by maintainers.

So instead of installing JMeter using package manager you can just download the latest [JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) (which is [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) as of now while in repositories you have much older versions, 2.11/2.13) from the official website. JMeter is pure Java-based application so all you will need to do in order to be able to use it is to install [Java 8 or above](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

---

Alternative option would be downloading [jmeter-jdbc JAR](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_jdbc) appropriate to your JMeter version and dropping it under `/usr/share/jmeter/lib/ext` folder (super-user privileges might be required), this way you will get JDBC test elements.